# Does GetMessage need a GUI

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

Many years ago I learned that in order to use GetMessage you need some form of GUI.
Without it windows don't create a message-queue.

Was I taught wrongly?

EDIT:
MSDN says: *Because the system directs messages to individual windows in an application, a thread must create at least one window before starting its message loop.*

It seems I was taught well, or is there more?

Comment: I would read that MSDN statement as an advisory, rather than a requirement. Windows itself won't send any messages to you without a window, but it is possible for your own program to send itself messages, from another thread for example. I wonder too about calls such as SetTimer which allow a null HWND parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You confuse some things here.

First of all you **can** use `GetMessage` without creating live windows in your thread.

OTOH the OS doesn't create the message queue for the newly created thread by default. Hence - calls like `PostThreadMessage` to the newly created thread may fail.

To enforce the creation of the message queue you need to call any function that is supposed to operate on this thread's queue **from this thread**.

In simple words, just call `PeekMessage` in that thread.

More info is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

(see remarks)

Answer (score 0):

The calls to [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) require a HWND for a parameter. If you don't have a window, you won't have a HWND, and you can't receive messages whether you have a message queue or not.

**Edit:** I take it back.  [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to pass a NULL parameter for the HWND, and [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx) will post a message to the queue without an HWND. PostMessage also allows a NULL for the HWND parameter.

I learn something new every day!

Comment: Not exactly true. There are windowless messages (COM does this).